# Date object to get time and convert to 24 hours string time e.g) "3:18" without second javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

Trying to get time from date object in javascript in this format without second, e.g) "3:18" or "15:18" if pm. So date object is `Tue Jun 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` Please help me with this

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: I tried that that does not work

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleString('default',{hour:'numeric',minute:'2-digit',hour12:false})`. See [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1450.4192)